# Cursor is Not Changing When Hovering Over an Element

Tags: html, css, cursor

I am working on some code, and it looks fine, but the `cursor` is not updating to a `pointer` when it `hover`s over the `element`. Here's my code:

```css
.searchProgramsResultTab {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #DADBDB;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #2BC2D3;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px groove #686868;
}
.searchProgramsAdditional1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #47BC47;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.searchProgramsBar {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 500px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #0F0F0F;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.searchProgramsAdditional2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 550px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #D41B1B;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.lastVisited {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 950px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #707070;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.lastVisitedTime {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 1105px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #D41B1B;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: default;
}
.hoverText:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class = "searchProgramsResultTab" id = "searchProgramsResult1">
      <span class = "programName hoverText" id = "programName1">Name - Bob</span>
      <span class = "searchProgramsAdditional1 hoverText" id = "searchProgramsAdditional11">Save for later</span>
      <span class = "searchProgramsBar"> - </span>
      <span class = "searchProgramsAdditional2 hoverText" id = "searchProgramsAdditional12">Report a bug</span>
      <span class = "lastVisited">Last visited: </span><span class = "lastVisitedTime">Never</span>
    </div>
```

Don't worry about the bad formatting, I just want to see why it is not changing the `cursor`.

Comment: its changing on the span that has the text **Name - Bob**

Comment: Check your `z-index`s - or lack thereof, you have a lot of stacking concerns to address there.

Comment: place your mouse exact on the this text **Name - Bob** and your cursor will turned to pointer

Comment: Everything is working fine but you are just giving them an extra padding thats why your cursor is not changing

Comment: Just look into this fiddle i have remove all your paddings and put **<br/>** to check your problem  https://jsfiddle.net/5ymfgqpo/

Comment: every element have a position fixed and the with some paddings.
Problem here is that your lastvisited elements padding is overlapping here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **Position:fixed;** for these elements. and giving them some padding.

```
.searchProgramsAdditional1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;

  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #47BC47;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.searchProgramsBar {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;

  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #0F0F0F;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.searchProgramsAdditional2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;

  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #D41B1B;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
```

This is your last element

```
.lastVisited {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;

  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #707070;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
```

**This last element is overlapping on the other Elements**

I have removed all the padding and put 
 breaklines to check the problem and cursor works
[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5ymfgqpo/)

Answer (score 0):

The hoverText class should be applied to the div element instead of the first span element for "Name - Bob".

I've copied your code with this change below.

```css
.searchProgramsResultTab {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #DADBDB;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #2BC2D3;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px groove #686868;
}
.searchProgramsAdditional1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #47BC47;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.searchProgramsBar {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 500px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #0F0F0F;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.searchProgramsAdditional2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 550px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #D41B1B;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.lastVisited {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 950px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #707070;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.lastVisitedTime {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 1105px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #D41B1B;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: default;
}
.hoverText:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class = "searchProgramsResultTab hoverText" id=
"searchProgramsResult1">
      <span class = "programName" id = "programName1">Name - Bob</span>
      <span class = "searchProgramsAdditional1 hoverText" id = "searchProgramsAdditional11">Save for later</span>
      <span class = "searchProgramsBar"> - </span>
      <span class = "searchProgramsAdditional2 hoverText" id = "searchProgramsAdditional12">Report a bug</span>
      <span class = "lastVisited">Last visited: </span><span class = "lastVisitedTime">Never</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: but he want different cursor for different elements

Comment: you solution will put cursor on all the elements as he is using **cursro:default**  in case of *lastvisitedTime* class

Comment: Did you try my solution?  That is not what happens.  It changes to the pointer on the elements where the hoverText class is applied.

Comment: yeah it is not working as expected as he is using **hoverText** for secondlast element also

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I thought the question was why the cursor was not changing as it entered the box containing "Name - Bob"

Comment: it changing for **Name-Bob** but not for that last element i have answered him.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper to hold your fixed elements.

Also some minor improvement in structure, see it yourself.

(fixed/absolute elements are tricky, read about the documentation before using them)

your hover (pointer) is not working because of stacking, set z-index to 1 for those elements and you will see it is working.

```css
.searchProgramsResultTab {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #DADBDB;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #2BC2D3;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px groove #686868;
}

.searchProgramsAdditional1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #47BC47;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.searchProgramsBar {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #0F0F0F;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.searchProgramsAdditional2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #D41B1B;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.lastVisited {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #707070;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.lastVisitedTime {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #D41B1B;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: default;
}

.hoverText {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hoverText:hover {
  background: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
}

.lastVisitedWrapper {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchProgramsResultTab" id="searchProgramsResult1">
  <span class="programName hoverText" id="programName1">Name - Bob</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="searchProgramsAdditional1 hoverText" id="searchProgramsAdditional11">Save for later</span>
  <span class="searchProgramsBar"> - </span>
  <span class="searchProgramsAdditional2 hoverText" id="searchProgramsAdditional12">Report a bug</span>
  <span class="lastVisitedWrapper">
    <span class="lastVisited">Last visited: </span>
  <span class="lastVisitedTime">Never</span>
  </span>
</div>


<pre>
1
2
3
21
312
3
12
3
123
213
123
123
12
1
2
3
21
312
3
12
3
123
213
123
123
12
1
2
3
21
312
3
12
3
123
213
123
123
12
1
2
3
21
312
3
12
3
123
213
123
123
12
1
2
3
21
312
3
12
3
123
213
123
123
12
1
2
3
21
312
3
12
3
123
213
123
123
12
</pre>
```